# How to get a proper error message in Azure B2C built-in signup flow

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I'm using the built-in azure b2c sign up user flow in my application. The signup form doesn't give the proper validation messages. It always gives one generic message and it's always located at the top. Is there any way to customize this message and put it below the input field, that failed the validation?

The following image shows one scenario where the password is week. but still, the error message has no indication about the password.

[image]

Comment: Do you use custom ui in the sign up user flow?

Comment: @AllenWu yes. I'm using a custom UI.

Comment: Share how you set  [Localization string IDs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/localization-string-ids#sign-up-and-self-asserted-pages-user-interface-elements) in your custom ui file.

Comment: @AllenWu this comes with a custom user flow. not with a custom UI, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take a look at this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/localization#predicate using predicates to define the error message displayed to a user.

Comment: Thank you sir. I followed the document and it's working as expected.

Comment: @AyeshNipun anytime sir!